# Add attachment for new contact in salesforce using c#

Tags: c#, salesforce

We need to add an attachment for new contact. We are using APEX class for adding new contact. We are able create new contact. we need to maintain the Order information for a contact. This is not possible with the available fields/custom fields. So we are going to try with attachment. a customer may have multiple orders.
Can you please let me know how to add attachment for a contact using c#.

Please find the below code snippet:

```
Contact newContact = new Contact();

newContact.LastName = downloadInformation.Name;
newContact.Email = downloadInformation.Email;

try
{
    SforceService salesForce = new SforceService();
    MySFServiceService mySFServive = new MySFServiceService();
    mySFServive.SessionHeaderValue = new SForce.MyService.SessionHeader();

    LoginResult loginResult = salesForce.login("id", "password");
    mySFServive.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;
    // UserRegistration is a method defined in our apex class.
    // parametter 1: contact object parameter
    // 2: account name
    mySFServive.UserRegistration(newContact, "Test Account");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the enterprise WSDL into your app (which it looks like you already have), then you'd create an instance of the attachment object,set its body to the order blob, and set the parentId to be the id of the contact. So you'd need to update your custom UserRegistration call to return the created contactId, then you could do.

```
salesforce.SessionHeaderValue = new SforceService.SessionHeader();
salesforce.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;
salesforce.Url = loginResult.serverUrl;
...
String contactId = mySFervive.UserRegistration(....);
Attachment a = new Attachment();
a.Body = readFileIntoByteArray(someFile);
a.parentId = contactId;
a.Name = "Order #1";

SaveResult sr = salesforce.create(new SObject [] {a})[0];
if (sr.success){ 
// sr.id contains id of newly created attachment
} else {
 //sr.errors[0] contains reason why attachment couldn't be created.
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I have changed my code like below. But I got exception like 
"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService" while calling the create method. 


  string newContactId= mySFServive.UserRegistration(newContact, "Test Account");
  ...
  ...

                attachment.ParentId = newContactId;   
   SaveResult sr=  salesForce.create(new SForce.Enterprise.sObject[]{ attachment})[0];

Comment: you're missing the salesforce.url=loginresult.serverUrl line.

Comment: Hi Superfell, Thanks for your help. I have included that line. now I am getting another exception in same line. "INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session"

Comment: you are missing the first 2 lines from my answer.

Comment: can you please clear my below doubts:
1. what is the minimum and maximum file size limit for an attachment? I think max is 5 MB.
2. How many attachments can attach for a single contact? 
3. Is any size limit is there for a single contact?
4. I want to attach files for more number of contacts. Is any limit is there for overall attachments? 

Thanks.

Comment: 5Mb per attachment, no other limits other than overal storage usage

Comment: How to know overall storage limit?

Comment: useful links to know storage limits:              http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000IYgPEAW
      https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits.htm&language=en#AppSetupLimitsSectionTitle

Comment: Hi superfell, can you please check the below query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638276/how-to-get-update-an-attachment-in-salesforce-using-c-sharp